# how to assign unpredictable url for web pages in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am developing an application in php that contains a lot of html pages that doesnot require user log in for viewing (a requirement actually). The pages are placed in different folders that are highly predictable. e.g www.abc.com/book1/chapter1/lesson1.php, www.abc.com/book1/chapter1/lesson2.php etc.

Hence if someone knows the path to lesson 1, he automatically knows the path to every other lesson in the chapter folder.

Is there a way that if there's a request for www.abc.com/book1/chapter1/lesson1.php, the path shown in the browsers address bar is something like www.abc.com/book1/chapterHFG564/6756/lesson1.php or any other unpredictable URL? i dont even know if it's possible or not!

Comment: So, you want to use unpredictable URL instead of user login?

Comment: like you said, even if it is unpredictable like www.abc.com/book1/chapterHFG564/6756/lesson1.php. If someone find out this address also, then he can easily find out the remaining lessons also just by changing the last thing to lesson2.php (www.abc.com/book1/chapterHFG564/6756/lesson2.php). then same as the simple url.

Comment: no for lesson2, it wud b different some thing like www.abc.com/book1/chapterHF/8766/lesson2.php...so the adress for every lesson is random!

Comment: How will you share these unpredictable URLs to your users?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3195/discussion-between-emaillenin-and-salman-mahmood)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an MD5 hash of the relative path of the page URL + the server timestamp to make an unpredictable string (let's call this a "page key"), and then store the page key + relative URL association in a persistent store (relational database, or - for speed - [constant database](http://cr.yp.to/cdb.html)) for later lookup.

Then you could write a script (like "http://www.abc.com/page_mapper.php") that takes a "key" parameter, looks up the relative URL for the specified key, reads the associated content (if there is any), and "passes it through" to the client.

Finally, you could add a [URL rewriting rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) to map incoming requests (e.g. "http://www.abc.com/book1/chapter2/abCvx9100xvz==") to your script (e.g. "http://www.abc.com/page_mapper.php?key=abCvx9100xvz==") and you'd be all set.

Of course then anyone who knows the URL can access the page, but maybe you want that?
i.e. is it OK if user A emails a link (that she can see) to user B and user B can see it?

Answer (score 0):

When it's unpredictable, it's impossible to do so. You can direct all urls to one php file which would then redirect user to correct url

Comment: im sorry...dint get u. whats impossible?

Comment: @Salmanmahmood: "how to assign unpredictable url for web pages in php"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if u can encode urls in that way... but u could certainly get all scripts to redirect to another MEGA script and use session variables or files to check and see where the user is comong from.. and proceed accordingly. Once the MEGA script directs to another page, it saves a session variable first.. which u can check once the redirect landing page opens up.